# First non-repeating character of a string

Tags: c, arrays, string, algorithm, character

According to geekforgeeks http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/given-a-string-find-its-first-non-repeating-character/ 1 solution would be:

"use a count array by storing not just counts but also the index of the first time you encountered the character e.g. (3, 26) for ‘a’ meaning that ‘a’ got counted 3 times and the first time it was seen is at position 26. So when it comes to finding the first non-repeater, we just have to scan the count array, instead of the string"

That is fine, but someone suggested this -> "Instead of traversing from left to right, traverse from right to left and maintain the count array and keep the record of character that occurs only one time.
This will save the space for storing index and requires only one pass."

And that is where I'm confused, I mean what would be the benefit over going right to left and save time?

Answer (score 2):

There is no benefit for changing direction.

At the first phase you need to traverse string and count characters. Either direction will do.

At second phase you find first item in list with count 1.

There is not point trying to keep track of last single character, because it can be invalidated by later characters. Consider `"bba"`: When reading from right to left, last character is first `a`, and then `b`, which then invalidated by second `b`.

Comment: Yep. The only (miniscule) benefit of going backwards would be that you can overwrite the position array unconditionally.